Should question asking for reference to list of JavaScript events be reworded to ask for list directly?
I searched for "complete list of JavaScript events". The top result was: Reference that lists available JavaScript events?
It's closed for an obvious reason. I wonder if it could or should be edited so it can be answered directly (citing sources, of course).
Or is the list of possible JavaScript events just too long for that to be feasible? (I guess there's a hundred or so, and know the most common ones would be just a few dozen, but it may have a long tail.)

Are questions asking for one exhaustive list on-topic?

@yivi good find. This seems to list some times when list questions are good (the four dot points are helpful). I'd argue a 5th one could be 'relevance' or 'importance'. Events are central to JavaScript (as opposed to being lesser-known feature) so it might lean in favour of greater importance/relevance.

I wouldn't say around 100 items is a "limited" number, here; I'd suggest limited is at most around 10. Also, are the events available in JavaScript unlikely to change? Has there been any added recently (in the last 10 years?) If the answer is yes, then change in the future is likely the list will change again.

It's not very useful IMO. In general you'd be interested in what default events a specific HTML component has, and that information is available on numerous websites as well as the autocomplete feature of any decent editor. A list of events is just curiosity, the actual valuable information is "what events does a select box have", as an example.

@Gimby  can confirm (at least in my solitary case) it’s just curiosity. I had my mind blown today when I asked an LLM the same question. Had no idea of the breadth of various domains events pertain to (knew about stuff like clicks and key presses; didn’t know about websocket, sensor, network, and performance monitoring events)

Exactly. Curiosity is not a very good foundation for a website driven by usefulness.

@Gimby read the next sentence, and consider the utility of applications that can respond in various ways to things like websocket events, network dis/reconnections, and performance changes. Incredible (and incredibly useful!). Evoking curiosity certainly doesn’t imply an absence of utility, in fact, the opposite is very often true.

"Evoking curiosity certainly doesn’t imply an absence of utility" also "curiosity" doesn't mean it's useful. I'm curious how many bananas are there in the world. Real exact number of individual fruits. That's not exactly useful, though. Things like export volume of bananas for a period of time is much more useful. Similarly, listing every single event isn't quite useful, either. It won't leave room for how to work with those events. Moreover, it would be very hard to find what you're interested in - websocket events will be buried after a bunch of mouse events. And the two aren't alike.

I do not see how such a question would be useful. It is essentially "replicate multiple pages from documentation and keep them up to date in perpetuity".
There are many events but also events can come from or apply to different objects. There are

48 element events for elements.
33 events for media elements.
7 drag and drop events.
also1 touch events, device orientation events, mouse events, UI events just to name a few more.

But this incomplete list is just for the DOM events. There are more EventTargets that exist and emit events. For example: a WebSocket.
Trying to exhaustively list all the Web API events is a chore. trying to maintain this list - an even bigger one, since more and more ones are added all the time to accommodate various hardware, software features, use cases, etc. Moreover, it still does not answer the question. To actually provide a complete list of JavaScript events, we also need to look at Node.js events. There is also Deno and Bun - I am not really sure if they definde different events or not. I am not going to look it up, either because that is not the point of this post.
Point is, there are MANY events to talk about. I am not even being flippant and trying to list any libraries/frameworks with event emitting/listening in them. A simple list is going to be inadequate. And anything more than listing them is just re-doing the documentation but in a more inconvenient way.
1 I cannot really be bothered tracking down all the sources of documentation, so just listing a few now
